# How to calculate Quarter Over Quarter %change when the dataset is monthly

Tags: r, dplyr, zoo

I have this df which observations are monthly represented:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

Date <- seq(from = as_date("2019-11-01"), to = as_date("2020-10-01"), by = "month")

A <- (10:21)

df <- data.frame(Date, A)
```

```
view(df)

    Date         A
   <date>     <int>
 1 2019-11-01    10
 2 2019-12-01    11
 3 2020-01-01    12
 4 2020-02-01    13
 5 2020-03-01    14
 6 2020-04-01    15
 7 2020-05-01    16
 8 2020-06-01    17
 9 2020-07-01    18
10 2020-08-01    19
11 2020-09-01    20
12 2020-10-01    21
```

Using `lag()` I know how to calculate %change from Month over Month (MoM), but haven't been able to compare a quarter with the previous quarter: i.e, the sum of 3 months compared with the previous 3 months summed. I tried a loop approach but it didn't work and there should be a more efficient approach.

I appreciate it if someone can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `as.yearqtr` from `zoo` to convert the 'Date' column to quarter, do a group by `sum` and then get the `Diff`erence between the current and next (`lead`) or current and previous (`lag`)

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)
df %>%
      group_by(Quarter = as.yearqtr(Date)) %>%
      summarise(A = sum(A), .groups = 'drop') %>%
      mutate(Diff = lead(A) - A)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#  Quarter       A  Diff
#  <yearqtr> <int> <int>
#1 2019 Q4      21    18
#2 2020 Q1      39     9
#3 2020 Q2      48     9
#4 2020 Q3      57   -36
#5 2020 Q4      21    NA
```